# how to used < and > inside form input tag of spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using spring for developing application. When I write `'placeholder="<Last, First>" '` eclipse shows error message `multiple attribute founds. Missing end tag for "form:input"`

```
<form:input path="name" size="25" class="inputPrompt" placeholder="<Last, First>"/>
```

Is it possible to apply escape character inside spring input tag of placeholder attribute?

Comment: And what is placeholder? is it an Spring Form tag attribute? Can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Try these below options

**Try 1**

```
<fmt:message key="placeholderVar" var="\<Last, First\>"/>
<form:input placeholder="${placeholderVar}"  path="name" size="25" class="inputPrompt" type="text" />
```

**Try 2**

```
<form:input path="name" size="25" class="inputPrompt" placeholder="&lt;Last, First&gt;"/>
```